# Add "how to get started in roleplaying games to the FAQ". Also, start a FAQ?

Tags: discussion

We get questions from excited users who want to get started with roleplaying games, but mostly what we do is shut them down.

- [How can I acquire free two-player D&D Basic/Expert adventures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41670/me-and-my-girlfriend-wanna-start-playing-where-do-we-start)
- [I want to take part!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41530/i-want-to-take-part)

Also, we don't have an obvious FAQ.  There's https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour, but no obvious FAQ that I can find.

I propose we write up a canonical “Getting Started with Roleplaying Games” answer that we can direct such users to, put it prominently at the top of our FAQ (or, barring that, the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) page).

Comment: As much as I want to help the users in both those questions I think voting to close was the only good course of action. Both of those questions were too broad and lacked any requirements. Obviously its because the users had no idea as neophytes to the hobby, but there are other resources (forums mostly) that can better address this than we can. Once they get grounding in the hobby and start to have answerable (and definable) problems then we can help them out.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith I agree that closing was the correct answer. I'd just like to direct them somewhere useful afterward.

Comment: For future readers: [the FAQ Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange is here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/33569).

Answer (score 7):

SE is just a pile of questions. The frequently-asked ones are identified organically as people vote to close questions as duplicates of others.

That should be sufficient for this case. If these seem like they count as "Frequently Asked Questions" but aren't linked as duplicates, you can flag them for moderator attention with a message about the duplication.

Even if it wasn't redundant, we don't have any ability to create arbitrary pages like a dedicated FAQ. If we need a better way for people to discover frequently asked questions, we should submit a feature request for such a page/sidebar. (Right now the "similar questions" list that shows up when writing a question is the closest we have, and I believe that does draw on duplication data, but I've always thought it wasn't very effective as a "FAQ interface.")

Answer (score 7):

We have that question, it's here: [What is role-playing, and where do I start?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start)

The site used to have a FAQ but the SE Overlords in their wisdom turned it into the help center. C'est la vie.

There is a [faq](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag on meta to designate things we want to put in there. We don't have loads of access to edit it though, so we keep that to the bare minimum.

Questions that should be prominent on the site, go vote 'em up and close things as duplicate on them when they come up.