# FAQ Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq

For frequently-asked questions common to all sites in the network, see [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](//rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/help).

### Asking questions

- [How do we ask and answer subjective questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/how-do-we-ask-and-answer-subjective-questions)
- [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/544/what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here)

  - [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic? [2015]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited)
  - [Are tool recommendation questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/are-tool-recommendation-questions-on-topic)
  - [Are questions about alignment on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic)
  - [Are character build or optimization questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic)
  - [Are campaign research questions on topic? [2012]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic-part-two)
  - [Are "choose your own adventure" questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/are-choose-your-own-adventure-questions-on-topic)
  - [Are "list questions" on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/are-list-questions-on-topic)
  - [Are questions about rule intent on-topic? [2022]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12157/52137)
- [I want to ask for recommendations, but that's off topic. Is there any way to ask my question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/i-want-to-ask-for-recommendations-but-thats-off-topic-is-there-any-way-to-ask)
- [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)
- [Should I use a narrow system tag, or use a broader tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-i-use-a-narrow-system-tag-or-go-broad-if-possible-and-use-system-agnosti)
- [How is the [system-agnostic] tag supposed to be used?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/how-is-the-system-agnostic-tag-supposed-to-be-used)
- [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question)
- [Should questions include System/Setting in title if tagged with system/setting?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/should-questions-include-system-setting-in-title-if-tagged-with-system-setting)

### Writing answers

- [What are the citation expectations of answers on RPG Stack Exchange?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange)
- [Is homebrew an acceptable answer to a question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-homebrew-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-question)
- [Should I be requesting people answer the question independently?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently)
- [How do we handle a desire to challenge the frame of a question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-do-we-handle-a-desire-to-challenge-the-frame-of-a-question)
- [What's a frame challenge?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge)

### Comments

- [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted)
- [Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)
- [Why is an answer being downvoted without any comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/why-is-an-answer-being-downvoted-without-any-comments)
- [A question has some facts majorly wrong: should I be correcting them in comments or an answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7111/52137)

### Etiquette

- [Can we affirm that RPG.SE embraces a plurality of playstyles?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/can-we-affirm-that-rpg-se-embraces-a-plurality-of-playstyles)
- [Is this site for experts, or not?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/is-this-site-for-experts-or-not)
- [Is profanity allowed on RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/is-profanity-allowed-on-rpg-se)
- [When a Question Changes Completely, Should it be a New Question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/when-a-question-changes-completely-should-it-be-a-new-question)
- [Eek! A troll in the Stack! What do I do?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6698)
- [What is an "edit war" and is it ever appropriate?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/what-is-an-edit-war-and-is-it-ever-appropriate)

### Editing and formatting

- [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text)
- [Is there a functional purpose to putting things in code text here?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/is-there-a-functional-purpose-to-putting-things-in-code-text-here)
- [Use real headers instead of fake headers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/use-real-headers-instead-of-fake-headers)
- [Is there a style guide for posts?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6367/is-there-a-style-guide-for-posts)
- [MathJax guide for RPG.SE: How to format pretty tables and equations?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10074/mathjax-guide-for-rpg-se-how-to-format-pretty-tables-and-equations)

### Community moderation and curation

- [Why was my question closed as too broad, unclear, or opinion-based?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/why-was-my-question-closed-as-too-broad-unclear-or-opinion-based)
- [How to deal with questions that just don't understand the scope of the RPG landscape?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands)
- [How to deal with feedback questions about house-rules?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-to-deal-with-feedback-questions-about-house-rules)
- [What should I do about spam questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-should-i-do-about-spam-questions)
- [How should we use Community Wiki? [2016]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/how-should-we-use-community-wiki-part-iii)
- [Does "Ask the DM / GM" equate to "Primarily opinion based?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7353/does-ask-the-dm-gm-equate-to-primarily-opinion-based)
- [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl)
- [What should I do when a question does not specify the game system being used?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/what-should-i-do-when-a-question-does-not-specify-the-game-system-being-used)

### Miscellaneous

- [How does all the various Stack Exchange functionality work?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/how-does-all-the-various-stack-exchange-functionality-work)
- [Can I send private messages to users?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/can-i-send-private-messages-to-users)

### External links

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Writing the Perfect Question by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

---

### Is your question missing? How to add a question to this FAQ:

First check whether it's part of the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Also check to see if a question tagged [faq-proposal](/questions/tagged/faq-proposal) matches your question.

If the question doesn't exist at all on meta yet, you'll need to create it first: [ask a new question on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) asking only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body. The answer goes in an answer.

Given you've checked all of the above, you can propoes a question for this FAQ using the following procedure:

1. Tag it as [faq-proposal](/questions/tagged/faq-proposal).
2. Propose its addition to the FAQ in [FAQ Proposal Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/faq-proposal-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange)
3. When the community is in favor of adding to the FAQ, diamond moderators will add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag plus a “[Return to FAQ Index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970)” link at the end of the question.

Comment: Modelled off of the [SE network FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), incorporating all our meta Qs currently tagged [[tag:faq]], and given a first pass at categorising.

Comment: (We may need a separate meta Q just to discuss the FAQ Index and do any community organising or decision-making related to it. Comments are undoubtedly going to be inadequate quickly!)

Comment: Some of these FAQs are outdated or duplicative. Is there a way to clean this up?

Comment: @Trish Yes! I believe the [current guidance for removing items from the FAQ Index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/faq-proposal-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange) is to post a new [[tag:discussion]] meta proposing a removal. For a larger general cleanup project I think a new [discussion] meta also makes sense. (Aside, perhaps a [[tag:faq-management]] tag might be useful to keep such metas together without filling up [[tag:faq-proposal]] or [[tag:faq]] itself, but that’s a tangential thought.)

Comment: Have [FAQ Maintenance 2023](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12364/faq-maintenance-2023) then! we ought to so that at least once in a while.