# Where's the FAQ? I can't seem to find it

Tags: support, meta

I've been looking for a while and I can't find the FAQ, would someone be kind enough to link it to me?

Comment: Should we tag this [faq] and risk a recursion paradox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FAQ Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970) is our local (meta.rpg.se) FAQ. (It's basically an organized list of all the meta questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).)

Here's the rpg.se Help Center: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help. It can be found in the speech-bubble dropdown menu at top right of the site, or in the site footer. Note that that's pretty-much boilerplate help text, common to all SE sites. All good to know, though!

Feel free to drop a comment if these don't cover what you're looking for.

Comment: You can also write `[help]` in a comment, which creates a link to the [help].

Comment: And entering `[faq]` in a comment will generate a link to the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @MikeQ: As does `[tour]`.

Comment: @sevensideddie nice catch--thanks.