# Thank you to the community

Tags: discussion

I'm 45 and table top RPGs have been a core part of my identity since I was 12, often the only way I had of socializing. Due to a variety of life circumstances, it has been about 2 years since I've been able to be in a game.  Until/unless I convince my girlfriend to give up 4 or so hours of our weekend time together, that's likely to stay the same (Bleh work+grad school).  So having this site for me to glance over and occasionally participate in has been a major lifeline to my sanity.

I am normally the type of person who reads all FAQs/Rules/etc. of any place I go into before I post.  Needless to say, I haven't had the time/energy to do that here. So to all the people who have been kind in directing me to the appropriate places, I am very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our "FAQ" are not always up to date anyway, and the consensus on other parts - like the line between a good designer reason question and a bad one - is not well documented. Nobody would skin you alive for not reading through them, we point you to where we have something if the need arises.

Just do as you do, stay respectful and we help you figure the rest out. Glad to have you!

Comment: Our FAQ is [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/faq-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange).